# View count is not correctly saving into the database

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click I am trying to save the view count, but its not correctly saving the count into the database. It behaves weirdly during onClick action, I am unable to figure out the reason, could someone please advise ?
Is it because of not having `event.preventDefault();`

```
const getClickCount = (idx) =>{

    console.log("Popular blog item::"+idx);
    const params = {
      id: idx
    }
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {            
        const res = await axios.get(`${appUrl}/service/incrementblogviews`, {params});
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }



const MostPopularBlogs = () =>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='trendingArea'>
    { popularResults.map (({id, blogdetails, tags, views, createdAt }) => (
      <a key={id}> 
        <div key={id} 
         onClick={
          () =>
            navigate("popularBlogDetails", {
              state: { id, blogdetails, views, createdAt}
            })
          } 
         className='popularArea'>
          <ReactMarkdown  children={blogdetails} className='dataDate renderElipsis tags readmoreLink views' remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}> 
          </ReactMarkdown>
          <div className='blogDate'>
            {moment(createdAt).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')}
             <a onClick={() => getClickCount(id)} className='readmoreLink'>
              Read more →
             </a>
             <div className='blogViews'>
            {views > 999 ? (views / 1000).toFixed(2) + "K" : views}
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </a>
    ))} 
  </div>
```

server.js

```
/* Adding a service to update blog view count during onClick on each blog item */

app.get('/service/incrementblogviews', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const blogId =  req.query.id;
    const dataCount = await BlogModel.findOne({ attributes: ['views'] }, {where: { id: blogId } });
    const incrementCount = dataCount.views + 1;
    var updateData = { views: incrementCount };
    const updateBlogviews = await BlogModel.update(updateData, {where: { id: blogId }});
    res.status(200).json({ success: true  });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: When i click first time, Its saving the view count into database , but during the rest of the clicks count saves weirldy into database ..

Comment: Any chance you can give a better description than "behaves weirdly"?

Comment: First click save correctly into db, but while performing rest of the clicks saves the View count for other blogs ..

Comment: So the same view count is displaying for multiple blogs